# How much motion is needed to trigger Significant Motion

Tags: android, sensors, motion

Tested the Significant Motion sample on [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/TriggerSensors.java) to learn more on this Trigger sensor. Unfortunately the sensor does not trigger. 
What do I do wrong?

code snipes

```
class TriggerListener extends TriggerEventListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private TextView mTextView;

    TriggerListener(Context context, TextView textView) {
        mContext = context;
        mTextView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
        if (event.values[0] == 1) {
            mTextView.append(mContext.getString(R.string.sig_motion) + "\n");
            mTextView.append(mContext.getString(R.string.sig_motion_auto_disabled) + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSigMotion;
    private TriggerListener mListener;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mSigMotion != null) mSensorManager.cancelTriggerSensor(mListener, mSigMotion);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSigMotion = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        mListener = new TriggerListener(this, mTextView);
        if (mSigMotion == null) {
            mTextView.append(getString(R.string.no_sig_motion) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and I found

```
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);
```

returned null. 
So maybe there is no Significant Motion Sensor in the device(or the virtual device). In following code from the sample

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mSigMotion != null && mSensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(mListener, mSigMotion))
        mTextView.append(getString(R.string.sig_motion_enabled) + "\n");
 }
```

`mSensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(mListener, mSigMotion))` is never executed.

Comment: @AI117 thanks for your reply, In the code above, from android.googlesource.com,  there should always be a comment in the mTextView, even if there is no Significant Motion Sensor. but I got no comment when running that code.